# socat throw error while trying to connect external mysql

Tags: mysql, docker, debian, socat

I try to connect 2 docker containers to each other via socat.
Inside of the `web` container, I'll use socat to bind the external `mysql`-container to Port 3306.

I do use this command line:

```bash
socat TCP:$MYSQL_CONTAINER_IP:$MYSQL_CONTAINER_PORT,fork,reuseaddr,unlink-early,user=root,group=root,mode=777 UNIX-LISTEN:$MY_SOCKET  &
```

While $MYSQL_CONTAINER_IP = 172.17.0.2
and $MYSQL_CONTAINER_PORT = 3306

$MY_SOCKET is set via:

```
    MY_SOCKET=$(mysql_config --socket)
```

and result in `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`

But if I run this command, I got this:

> 2022/05/29 06:43:54 socat[10267] E bind(6, {AF=1 "/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock"}, 29): No such file or directory

The `Web`-Docker-Container is `debian:buster` (Debian buster [10]),
The MySql Container is Debian `wheezy:latest`

Any Idea, why I got the above noticed error-message?

Comment: The standard MySQL client libraries can use a TCP socket without this extra indirection.  Can you configure your application to connect to `$MYSQL_CONTAINER_NAME:3306` and skip this extra step?

Comment: The background is the following: The Docker-Containers simulate a "real-server" environment. There - most of the time, the database is placed at localhost:3306. 
To prevent any re-configuration of the Web-Application itself, I do use this `socat` solution, to simulate the environment as expected by the Web-Application.

Comment: That sounds like you're trying to simulate a full installed server environment.  An actual virtual machine might be a better match for this setup.  If you can't configure the database location in the Web server (why not?) introducing the artificial `socat` relay doesn't seem like a good reproduction of your production environment.

Comment: It already worked very well for other projects (on older debian releases). It was an absolutely no-brainer to use. Do a MySQL-Dump, place it in the xst_dev directory, run `xst_db init`, run `xst_web` and all is up and running without any change at the Website-Sources.
I only have trouble to get it now again to run after Debian upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

The error message sounds like directory /var/run/mysqld/ does not exist in the environment where Socat is run. I'd recommend to check this.

However, the Socat command line you constructed, with the fork option on the TCP address, will try every second to establish another connection to the MySQL server, and from the second connection (and sub process) on the UNIX bind will fail.

For typical forwarder uses, you should have the listener with fork as the first address, and the connector (here TCP:) as second address.

Comment: ok, can you show me an example for this kind of constellation?

Comment: ok, you are right, this directory doesn't exist. 
I wonder if I have to install mariadb-server package to make it available, even if I pipe socat to that local port 3306.

Comment: I do not think that you need MySQL server package in the container, create the directory manually instead. Run a command like this:
`socat UNIX-LISTEN:$MY_SOCKET,fork,unlink-early,user=root,group=root,mode=777 TCP:$MYSQL_CONTAINER_IP:$MYSQL_CONTAINER_PORT`